# Switching between image and video in android

Tags: android

I want to implement the concept of showing a gallery of images and videos that scrolls at the top of the android screen landscape and upon selection of one image or video, it gets displayed as a larger image in the lower part.ImageSwitcher can be used but it is only for images not videos, i want to switch between images and videos.

Comment: So you add images and the first image from the videos in the gallery. You want upon selection the video to start automatically? I think you could implement a SelectionListener and check if the selected image belongs to a video start it.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the first part please. No i dont want to start the video automatically upon selection, ImageSwitcher serves my purpose except if i can also include videos along with the images.

Comment: Can anyone help me to solve this please..

Comment: What I was saying is that you don't need to add the video in an ImageSwitcher from the beginning (while scrolling). You need to add the first frame/image from the video and when the user performs the action to start the video (e.g. clicks a button) you just replace (be careful about this, because it might look ugly, so maybe just play with the visibility instead of adding and removing views)  the ImageView with an VideoView and start the video. An example of how to play a video from the sdCard: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/blob/master/Media/Video/res/layout/main.xml

Comment: Please add more details if you want a detailed answer. For instance what kind of videos are you trying to play (format, are this you videos or provided by others)? Where are located (e.g. sdCard)? What have you tried so far (offer some code)?

Comment: I want to a show a gallery(Not in a grid or listview) of pictures and videos coming from server and on clicking of a picture/video show the preview of it below the gallery. Gallery should look something like horizontalscrollview.